# perpetual American-style call option

Tags: black-scholes

Greek “phi” for a derivative f is defined as its sensitivity to the changes in dividend
yield q : $$\phi = \frac{\partial f}{\partial q}$$

HOW CAN I FIND PHI WITHOUT THE CORRELATION?

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. You may get answers quicker if you show what you tried and what your thoughts are.

Comment: Again, not specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start by obtaining an expression for f:

In a B-S setting for the dynamics of the stock price with (continuous) dividend:

$$
  dS(t)= (\mu-q)S(t)dt+\sigma S(t)dW
  $$

The option has value $$f(S(t))$$

The value of the option follows

$$
df(S(t))= \frac{df}{dS}dS +\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dS^2} (dS)^2
$$

From here, you can use a replication argument (making the portfolio riskless) to get the PDE. Then, you can find a general form for the solution and pin it down using a boundary condition, a value-matching condition, and a smooth pasting condition.

The PDE will look like this (please double-check yourself) (' stands for derivative)

$$\frac{\sigma^2}{2}S^2f''(S) + (r-q)Sf'(S) - rf(S) =0$$

The general solution will have the form

$$f(S)= A_{1} S^{h1} + A_{2} S^{h2}$$

with $h1>1$ and $h2<0$

(h1 and h2 are the two solutions of the quadratic equation you get when plugging $A S^{h}$ back into the PDE.)

boundary condition

$$
lim_{x -> 0} (f) =0
$$

This tells you that one of the A's has to be 0 ( given the sign of h1 and h2)

Perpetual American options are exercised when the underlying hits a barrier level. Call $S^*$ this barrier.

Value matching

$$
f(S^{*}) = S^{*} -K
$$

(because it is a call option)

Smooth pasting

$$
f'(S^{*}) = 1
$$

This will give you an expression for f(S(t)). Next, you can take  the derivative w.r.t q for part a), and plug in numbers for b)

I hope this helps